# Python/BS4 - Use list as input in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scraper at the moment, right now I have it so it grabs a list of url's. I need it to use each of the url's in the list it makes one at a time into the soup function, to get my desired html output from each individual page.

Example:

```
my_list = ['www.google1213.com', 'www.yahoo123.com', 'www.apples123.com']

def main():

    url = input('URL: ') #List goes here
    currentDT = datetime.datetime.now() 
    scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper() 
    response = scraper.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
    #etc...#

while True:
main()
```

If anyone can help me get my list to send its contents so I scrape each url one at a time, I would be very greatful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    for url in my_list:
        currentDT = datetime.now()
        scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
        response = scraper.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop:

```
for url in my_list:
    print(url)
    # do your scrapping stuff...
```

Ps: maybe you should also limit your requests per second. Otherwise some websites will block you after a few tries.

Comment: Thanks, was struggling with this for a day.